# How can I check if image is publish on Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: typescript, azure, protractor, azure-blob-storage, e2e-testing

I write test with protractor and TypeScript. Testing e2e.
In test share image on azure blob storage.
I want to know. How can I check if image is correctly save in azure blob storage.
I do not received any link after share on azure.
Have you got a idea how can I do it, and automatic this?

Thanks for all your help

Comment: Please edit your question share your code for your test.

Comment: Sorry I do not have got a code to do that, beacuse I do not know how Can I do this

Answer (score 0):

To check the Publish image in **Azure blob storage**
Go to **Storage>Container>your created container** .

[image]

[image]

- Here is the sample [**`GitHub`**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-browser-file-upload-storage-blob) code to publish an image to Azure blob storage using typescript.

For more information please refer this MS DOC: [Upload Image to Azure blob staorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/browser-file-upload-azure-storage-blob)